# Selecting a Gradle build file from directory above using the command line

Tags: unix, command-line, build, directory, gradle

I'm building a shell script that does a gradle build and then run my grunt build after it is done and I'm storing this shell script in a subdirectory but the the graddle wrapper is in the root directory of the file.  My shell script looks like this

```
sh .././gradle ../build.gradle clean build 
grunt build
```

So when I call the script from the root directory it looks like this

```
$ sh gradle fullbuild
```

It errors out saying that

```
Execution failed for task ':fullbuild'. > Process 'command 'sh'' finished with non-zero exit value 127
```

When I do the first command from the script in the sub directory it says

```
FAILURE: Could not determine which tasks to execute. * What went wrong: Task '../build.gradle' not found in root project 'tools'.
```

Can I call gradle from a subdirectory and use that directories build.gradle file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `-b` flag you can indicate which build file to use. Try

```
sh ../gradle -b ../build.gradle clean build
```

You could also specify the `-p` flag instead which indicates which directory is the project dir.